Compose equivalent of layout_toLeftOf
I don't even know what to google...
I have the following layout:
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = thatText,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1
        )
        Text(text = someText)
    }
    FilledTonalButton(
        onClick = { }) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}

Which looks like:
thatText              | ////////////
----------------------| // Button //
someText              | ////////////

Now when thatText becomes too long it deforms the Button:
                             | /////
                             | // //
                             | // //
thatText that is really long | // //
-----------------------------| // //
someText                     | // //
                             | // //
                             | // //
                             | /////

But I would like it to be:
thatText that is r... | ////////////
----------------------| // Button //
someText              | ////////////

In xml I would do
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/my_button">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/share_file_detail_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

How do I achieve that in compose?

Add weight to the Column and achieve this even with the larger text, A button doesn't collapse.

Here is the code.
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(Modifier.weight(1f)) { // weight added here
            Text(
                text = "thatText",
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1
            )
            Text(text = "someText")
        }
        FilledTonalButton(
            onClick = { }) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }


Thank you! I realized I was adding weight to thatText earlier... facepalm
